# Sum of power and Bernoulli intuitive discover

Tags: exponential-sum, bernoulli-numbers

I really looked up to the 10th page of google, and the PDF's I find aren't complete, and definetively have NOT intuitive explanation about Bernoulli's discover. I know that he observed the formulas of the sum of the $n$-th power, and noticed some pattern. But I wanted to know about this pattern, and how to come up with a formula that generates these numbers.

Thank you

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=awAfO7Ff_z0C&q=bernoulli#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Good -and as I find: very intuitive- explanations about the history of finding that polynomials are in Ed Sandifer's "How Euler did it" and Donald Knuth's article on "Faulhaber's formula", both articles can be found via google and are online